# Вывод сообщения по ключу. Ничего не отражает

Tags: reactjs

Если смотреть логи, то кода мы передаем Key, то запрос все таки уходит и возвращает Json. Но сам код ничего не выводит на экран. В чем проблема?

```
import React, { FC, ReactElement, useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Client, MessageLookupDto } from '../api/api';
import { FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap';

const apiClient = new Client('https://localhost:44356');

const MessageList: FC<{}> = (): ReactElement => {
    let textInput = useRef(null);
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState<MessageLookupDto[] | undefined>(undefined);
    let messageKey = 'c174340f-3ebb-44e2-82f5-40eb8fa5a4e0'

    async function getMessages() {
        const messageListVm = await apiClient.get(messageKey, '1.0');
        setMessages(messageListVm.messages);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(getMessages, 500);
    }, []);
    

    const handleKeyPress = (event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            messageKey = event.currentTarget.value.toString();
            getMessages()
            event.currentTarget.value = '';
            setTimeout(getMessages, 500);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            Messages
            <div>
                <br/>
                <div>Enter the key</div>
                <FormControl ref={textInput} onKeyPress={handleKeyPress} />
            </div>
            <section className='mainsec'>
            <br/>
                {messages?.map((message) => (
                    <div>
                        <div>Title: {message.title}</div>
                        <div>Text: {message.text}</div>
                        <div>View key: {message.uploadUrl?.slice(-36)}</div>
                        <br/>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </section>
        </div>
    );
};

export default MessageList;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в ваше json есть вот такая структура `messageListVm.messages`. Смотрели, что именно приходит, что сохранилось в состоянии?

Comment: Сейчас посмотрю

Comment: Добавил картинку что хранится в messageListVm

Comment: А вот в messageListVm.messages undefined

Comment: **Не добавляйте код и тексты ошибок картинками**... глаза можно сломать. `messageListVm.messages` undefined потому как его нет в вашем входящем объекте

Comment: а что проверить по другому что в нем хранится? До сих пор не решил проблему

Comment: Вам в ответе от вашего API приходит объект, у которого нет ключа message. Скорее всего вам надо добавлять весь полученный ответ в состояние. Так же, вы получаете объект, а в рендере обращаетесь к массиву. Тут тоже все сломается. В стейт надо положить объект с 1 элементом

Comment: можете наглядно показать как быть с кодом, не получается, ошибки вылетеают

Comment: Выполните `console.log(messageListVm)` и полученный результат скопируйте **текстом** и вставьте в ваш вопрос. Тогда можно будет подумать, что не так. Перебивать структуру ответа с картинки не хочется, да и можно ошибиться

Comment: на изображение #2 полученный результат как раз

Comment: Тогда перечитайте [мой комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1480123/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d1%83-%d0%9d%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82?noredirect=1#comment2651143_1480123)

Comment: messageListVm.message это массив не может быть представленно как один элемент. В нем надо по ключу искать нужный нам?

Answer (score 0):

Ваша функция получения сообщения должна выглядеть вот так:

```
async function getMessages() {
    const messageListVm = await apiClient.get(messageKey, '1.0');
    setMessages([ messageListVm ]);
}
```

Можно сократить

```
async function getMessages() {
    setMessages([ await apiClient.get(messageKey, '1.0') ]);
}
```

Ваш `apiClient.get` возвращает объект(**object**), в котором нет ключа **messages**.

При этом же, ответ и есть нужный вам элемент.

Для того, что бы методе **render** был данный элемент отрисован корректно и не надо было переписывать компонент, то полученный ответ положим в массив и сохраним в `messages`. Теперь в render `messages?.map()` отработает и отобразит 1 элемент

Comment: Аргумент типа "MessageListVm[]" нельзя назначить параметру типа "SetStateAction<MessageLookupDto | undefined>"

Comment: У типа "MessageListVm" нет общих свойств с типом "MessageLookupDto"

Comment: @MrPrograMax Проверяйте ваши типы. Скорее всего заданная структура не соответствует реальным данным, которые вы получаете. Либо менять возвращаемый тип у `apiClient.get` либо менять тип `MessageLookupDto`.

Comment: MessageListVm имеет сво-во в Api IList<MessageLookupDto> Messages

Comment: MessageLookupDto это просто его отображение при запросе

Comment: ну если интересно все же решить проблему https://github.com/MrPrograMax ссылка на мой гитхаб, каждый из репозиториев отвечает за свою задачу

Comment: если найде проблему свяжитесь со мной в телеграмме например https://t.me/TheDesireToBelieve

Comment: Сделайте вот так `const [messages, setMessages] = useState<any[] | undefined>(undefined);` и убедитесь, что работает. После этого вам надо разобраться с вашим описанием типов. Это уже к вопросу не относится. Хотите что бы вам помогли с типами, оформите новый вопрос, куда приложите пробемные типы с ошибками, которые у вас выдаются и вам помогут с этим.

Comment: у меня проблема на уровне фронтэнда. Если рассматривать api например в swagger все работает отлично

Comment: Ваш последний комментарий работает, только key не отражает, ну это не срашно. Пукай так, спасибо вам большое!

Comment: Не отображает потому, что его нет в вашем ответе :) Тип данных `any` это не очень хорошая штука. Поэтому рекомендую разобраться с типизацией

Comment: не сильно в react разбираюсь, но нужно по заданию